# How to seamlessly connect different colored lines in a PyPlot plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a simple visualizing function in python using pyplot. It takes a dataframe, an upper and lower limit and the start/end points to visualize. Here is the full code:

```
def visualize(DATASET, DATASET_LIMITS, DATASET_START, DATASET_END):
#     DATASET        = df_I
#     DATASET_LIMITS = df_I_limits
#     DATASET_START  = 0
#     DATASET_END    = len(df_I)

    plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
    values = []
    values_above = []
    for data in DATASET['Temp'].iloc[DATASET_START:DATASET_END]:
        if data < DATASET_LIMITS[0] or data > DATASET_LIMITS[1]:
            values.append(math.nan)
            values_above.append(data)
        else:
            values.append(data)
            values_above.append(math.nan)

    plt.plot(range(0, DATASET_END - DATASET_START), values, 'b-')
    plt.plot(range(0, DATASET_END - DATASET_START), values_above, 'r-')
    plt.hlines(DATASET_LIMITS[0], 0, DATASET_END - DATASET_START, colors='g', linestyles='dashed')
    plt.hlines(DATASET_LIMITS[1], 0, DATASET_END - DATASET_START, colors='g', linestyles='dashed')
    plt.show()
```

Here is what a generated graph looks like:
[image: Graph 1]

You can already see some gaps where the dotted-greed limit line bisects the graph, but here's a zoomed in version to show the problem more clearly. Here is just the largest spike in the data, in the ~205000 range:
[image: Graph 2]

You can clearly see that the red and blue segments of the graph are not connected. I believe this is likely due to the method that I use to visualize the data, that being two arrays - `values` and `values_above`. Is there a better way of accomplishing this graphing behaviour? Or perhaps a way to get connected lines using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide dataset, I'm going to post a simple function I usually use on this occasions.

You take the x and y coordinates from your dataframe and pass them to this function: `modify_coords(x, y, y_lim)` where `y_lim` is the y coordinates of the your horizontal line. This function will insert new points where the intersection happens. Then, you can proceed with your usual code.

```
def modify_coords(x, y, y_lim):
    """If a line segment defined by `(x1, y1) -> (x2, y2)` intercepts
    a limiting y-value, divide this segment by inserting a new point
    such that y_newpoint = y_lim.
    """
    xv, yv = [x[0]], [y[0]]
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        xc, xn = x[i:i+2]
        yc, yn = y[i:i+2]
        if ((yc < y_lim) and (yn > y_lim)) or ((yc > y_lim) and (yn < y_lim)):
            xv.append(((y_lim - yc) / ((yn - yc) / (xn - xc))) + xc)
            yv.append(y_lim)
        xv.append(xn)
        yv.append(yn)
    return np.array(xv), np.array(yv)
```

Note:

1. it uses linear interpolation to add the new points.
2. you can see this function in action at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72191963/filling-area-with-different-colors-when-line-cross-some-limit-plotly/), where I used a much smoother function as a test. You should give it a try on your data and eventually adapt it to achieve your goal.